# How to run a c program using loops to find the remainder of two numbers without using multiplication, division and modulo operators?

Tags: c, loops

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int num1, num2;

    printf ("Input value for num1: ");
    scanf ("%d", &num1);
    printf ("Input value for num2: ");
    scanf ("%d", &num2);   

    int prod =0, i;
    for(i = 1; i <= num1; i++){
        prod += num2;
    }

    int quo = 0 , rem = 0;
    for(rem = num1 - num2; rem >= 0; rem = rem-num2) {
        if(rem < 0)             
            break;
        else
            quo++;
    }

    //The last part is that i need to find the remainder without  using multiplication, division and the modulo itself.

    printf ("The product of %d and %d is: %d\n", num1, num2, prod);
    printf ("The integer quotient of %d and %d is: %d\n", num1, num2, quo);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And, I really dont know how to do it. I hope someone will help me.

Comment: You forgot to tell us the problem with the posted code

Comment: The remainder is `rem + num2`

Comment: Hint: 10 divided by 3 is 3 and the rest is 1. 10 - 3 = 7. 7 - 3 = 4. 4 - 3 = 1. Now 1 is smaller than 3 and 1 is the rest.

Comment: Note that `if(rem < 0) break; else` is unnecessary, it duplicates the loop condition `rem >= 0`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a **slow** calculation of `num1 % num2` (i.e. without multiplication/division) you can do:

```
// Calculate num1 % num2

unsigned rem(unsigned num1, unsigned num2)
{
    if (num2 == 0) {.... error handling ....}

    while (num1 >= num2) num1 -= num2;
    return num1;
}

int main(void)
{
    unsigned num1 = 42;
    unsigned num1 = 3;
    unsigned rem = rem(num1, num2);
    printf("%u", rem);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: where will i put this part? it keeps on saying  

error: ‘rem’ redeclared as different kind of symbol
   26 |     unsigned rem(unsigned num1, unsigned num2)
      |              ^~~

Comment: @serra You put the function before the `main()` function. I will make a complete example below.

Comment: @serra See my answer (above or below, it seems to move around :) )

Comment: @serra See update

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution for calculating `a mod b` for positive integers `a` and `b` with only subtraction and addition is to subtract `b` from `a` until the result is smaller than `a`. However, this takes many iterations if `b` is much smaller than `a`.

A method with better worst-case performance is the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned rem(unsigned a, unsigned b)
{
    if(b == 0) return 0;  // Error
    while(a >= b)
    {
        unsigned s = b;
        do
        {
            a = a - s;
            s = s + s;
        } while(a >= s);
    }
    return a;
}

int main(void)
{
    unsigned example = rem(32453, 3);
    printf("%u\n", example);
}
```

This method is based on the fact that to get closer to the result, we can subtract any multiple of `b` as long as it is smaller than `a`, so in each inner iteration we try to subtract twice the multiples of the last iteration until the subtractor becomes too large and we start over again with a single multiple of `b`.

Be aware that this will give wrong results if `s = s + s;` overflows the `unsigned` range. Hence, `a` should not be larger than half the upper limit of `unsigned`.